# Is it possible to pass a constructor that takes an argument into a set in C++?

Tags: c++, string, multiset

I was wondering if it was at all possible to pass a constructor that takes an argument to a comparison function into a set.

For example something like this:

```
class cmp
{
    private:
        string args_;
    public:
        cmp(const string& s):args_(s){}
        bool operator()(const int & a, const int& b)
            return a<b;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string s(argv[1]);
    multiset<int, cmp(s)> ms; //can i do this?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::set` and `std::multiset` have constructors, which take the comparator object:

```
explicit set (const Compare& comp = Compare(),
              const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The type of the `Compare` object is the second argument of the `std::set` or `std::multiset` template.

Comment: So it would be `multiset<int, cmp> ms(cmp(s));`.

Comment: oh that worked, but can i use that to insert into the multiset